# Variables being set to None in Python multithreaded app

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a small multi-threaded app in Python which has recently been giving me errors like:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "enrichment/twitter_enrichment.py", line 368, in run
    self.get_user()
  File "enrichment/twitter_enrichment.py", line 332, in get_user
    self.queueWorkItem.do_work(self.twitterClient)
  File "enrichment/twitter_enrichment.py", line 300, in do_work
    return work(twitterClient)
  File "enrichment/twitter_enrichment.py", line 284, in fetch_timeline
    self.user.newest_tweet_id_str
  File "enrichment/twitter_enrichment.py", line 94, in twitter_drain_timeline
    timeLine = twitter_fetch_timeline(client, user_id, since_id=since_id, max_id=max_id)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The method `twitter_fetch_timeline` is set in the parent thread.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/vCrHW28u) is the code which starts my threads.

This app runs for a while, then abruptly fails in this way.

In the same method that is currently failing, I was originally getting the error `NoneType object does not have attribute debug` because I was calling `logger.debug(...)` on a logger instance that was created in the parent thread. I fixed that with the following code, but now suspect I'm fixing symptoms rather than the issue:

```
    try:
        logger
    except NameError:
        logger = None
    finally:
        if logger == None:
            import logging
            logger = logging.getLogger('Twitter Enrichment')
```

What's the root issue I am missing?

Comment: Can you show the code which starts the processes?

Comment: Updated. Also, http://pastebin.com/vCrHW28u

Comment: Another update: It always saves 9 users' data before crashing. Always 9.